# How do I read and print the n string that I am reading from the user in this mini billing system project in C?

Tags: c

So I have this mini project from my college where I have to make a simple billing system in C.

Now, starting with the code, here's how I am asking the data that is to be inputted.

```
printf("How many items do you have in your basket?:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        printf("Enter the name of the item:\n");
        scanf("%s",&item_name[i]);


        printf("Enter the MRP printed on the box:\n");
        scanf("%f",&mrp[i]);

        printf("Enter the quantity:\n");
        scanf("%f",&qty[i]);
    }
```

Now,  suppose someone has 2 items in his basket and so, he'll enter two names. At the end, how do I print two names ??

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",item_name[i]);
        printf("Quantity:%.2f\n",qty[i] );
        printf("MRP:%.2f\n",mrp[i] );
    }
```

The code printed above only prints the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It prints properly, it's just your `scanf` which is wrong for char arrays. You don't have to pass the address of the pointer. As opposed to integer or doubles, passing the pointer is sufficient.

```
scanf("%s",&item_name[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s",item_name[i]);
```